# How to use Python SSHTunnle to forward multiple ports to two DB

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, mysql-python, ssh-tunnel, influxdb-python

I have a weather station base on Raspberry Pi that sends the data to two different `DB`s on another Raspberry Pi (for now all are local). Let's say the weather Raspberry Pi as `weather_client` and the other one as db_server.

On the `db_serve`r I have one `mysql`, `db` and one `influxDB`:

```
mysql port: 3306
influxDB port: 8086
```

At some point the `weather_client` will be not on local network, so I started to check `sshtunneling`, and for now I have the below working solution for reading `mysql` queries:

```
import os
import time
#import datetime
import MySQLdb

from datetime import datetime
from sshtunnel import SSHTunnelForwarder

import influxdb_client
from influxdb_client import InfluxDBClient, Point, WritePrecision, WriteOptions
from influxdb_client.client.write_api import SYNCHRONOUS

query = 'from(bucket:bucket)\
|> range(start: -5m)\
|> filter(fn:(r) => r._measurement == "rpi-bme280")\
|> filter(fn:(r) => r.location == "xxxx")\
|> filter(fn:(r) => r._field == "temperature")\
|> aggregateWindow(every: v.windowPeriod, fn: last, createEmpty: false)\
|> yield(name: "last")'

# Configure mysql connection variable
global db_cursor
global db

def read_from_mysqldb():
    try:
        db_cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM wind_data ORDER BY wind_data.id DESC LIMIT 1")
        result = db_cursor.fetchall()
        if result is not None:
            print ( '| time: ' , result[0][5], '| GrafanaId: ', result[0][1], '| location: ' , result[0][2], '| speed: ' , result[0][3], '| direction: ' , result[0][4],  '| id: ' , result[0][0])
    except:
        print ("read error")

def read_from_influxdb():
     try:
         result = query_api.query(org=org, query=query)
         results = []
         for table in result:
             for record in table.records:
                 results.append((record.get_field(), record.get_value()))
         print(results)
     except:
         print ("read error")

def main():
    while 1:
        read_from_mysqldb()
        #read_from_influxdb()
        time.sleep(15)

server = SSHTunnelForwarder(
    ('192.168.0.100', 22),
    ssh_username="pi",
    ssh_password="xxxxxx",
    remote_bind_address=("192.168.0.100", 3306)
)

# Configure InfluxDB connection variables
token = os.environ.get("INFLUXDB_TOKEN")
org = "mymeteo"
bucket = "test_enviro"

if __name__ == '__main__':
    server.start()

    print(server.local_bind_port)  # show assigned local port
    url = "http://192.168.0.100:" + str(server.local_bind_port)

    try:
        _client = InfluxDBClient(url=url, token=token)
        _query_api = _client.query_api()
        db = MySQLdb.connect(host="127.0.0.1", port=server.local_bind_port, user="root", password="xxxx", database="xxxxx")
        db_cursor = db.cursor()
    except:
        print ("Keine Verbindung zum Server...")

    try:
      main()
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
      print ("bye bye...")
      pass

db_cursor.close()
db.close()
server.stop()
```

Is it possible to use the same tunnel towards the two `DB`s with different ports?

I tried this but it gives me one assert error:

```
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/sshtunnel.py", line 149, in check_addresses
    assert all(isinstance(x, (tuple, string_types)) for x in address_list)
AssertionError
```

Changes in the sshtunnel line:

```
 tunnels = [("192.168.0.100", 3306),
            ("192.168.0.100", 8086)]

 server = SSHTunnelForwarder(
     ('192.168.0.100', 22),
     ssh_username="pi",
     ssh_password="password",
     remote_bind_address=tunnels
 )
```

How can I do this, maybe my thinking is wrong and the better solution would be to send the data to the DBs via php or!?